# OpenGL: How to add alpha channel to RGB texture

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, textures, alpha

There are 2 textures in memory, an RGB texture and a single channel texture that is it's alpha mask. Is there any way to combine the two in OpenGL? 
I'm currently combining the two in openCV and then passing the whole to openGL for rendering but the channel combination in openCV is too slow and I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: Yes, a compute shader should do the trick. (A pixel shader could too but its a bit more annoying to do IMHO).

Comment: Are you using shaders? if yes then you can do so in fragment shaders

Comment: @Asesh no, I haven't seriously used shaders yet and frankly wouldn't know where to begin. Should I look into how fragment shaders work? What's the correlation with openGL?

Comment: FFP has already been deprecated. You should consider using shaders instead.

Comment: To answer your second question, you should look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language